# Remove occurrences of value on a list if it matches condition

Tags: java

I have two lists:

```
List<Long> keys = new ArrayList();
List<Long> newKeys = ArrayList();
```

And I have a function that returns the list of new keys.

```
public List<Long> getNewKeys() {...}
```

So the keys must be stored on the `keys` list but they can only appear twice on the `keys` list.

Later on the code I do something like this:

```
newKeys.stream()
       .forEach(key -> {
           if(keyAlreadyOnList(key)) { //Checks if there is already two occurrences of the key on the keys list
               return;
           }
           ...
           keys.add(key);
       });
```

I would like to avoid that `if` inside the `forEach`, so ideally a filter would be applied to remove the values that already appear twice on the `keys` list or in case there are for instance 1 key on the `keys` array and two on the `newKeys` list on of the values of the `newKeys` list should be filtered out since the sum is 3.

Examples:

`Keys` = {};

`NewKeys` = {};

Nothing is removed.

`Keys` = {1};

`NewKeys` = {1};

Nothing is removed.

`Keys` = {1};

`NewKeys` = {1, 1};

One of the `1` is removed from the `newKeys` list

`Keys` = {1, 1};

`NewKeys` = {1, 1};

All occurrences of `1` areremoved from the `newKeys` list

`Keys` = {};

`NewKeys` = {1, 1, 1};

One of the `1` is removed from the `newKeys` list

Thanks

Comment: Make a `Set` from the list before processing, so it won't contain duplicate elements.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That doesn't solve the issue. Image the case of the `keys` list being empty and the `newKeys` contain the same key twice. It should be a valid scenario and it would add the key twice to the `keys` list

Comment: @kylie.zoltan then a filter before the `forEach` like `filter(Predicate.not(WhateverClass::keyAlreadyOnList))`

Comment: @Progman edited with some examples. In this case is possible to have duplicated keys. Is a requirement.

Comment: @kylie.zoltan Is the order of the keys important?

Comment: @Progman It's not important.

Comment: @kylie.zoltan Why do you want to "avoid" the `if()` statement in your `forEach()` block?

Comment: @Progman Yes, fixed thanks To look cleaner

Comment: @kylie.zoltan So, there is no problem but only a code styling issue? You *might* want to ask this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check their help pages first.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is

```java
newKeys.stream()
       .filter(not(this::keyAlreadyOnList))
       .forEach(keys::add);
```

I used static method `not` from `Predicate` class:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)